# Prove that if $2y > x$, then $p \geq q$

Tags: number-theory

**The result below has been disproven.**

> Let positive integers $p,q,x,y$ satisfy $5p+q = x$ and $5p-q = y$. Prove that if $2y > x$, then $p \geq q$.

Since $2y > x$, we have $2(5p-q) > 5p+q$ and so $5p > 3q$. This result holds true for $(5p+q,5p-q) = (6,4)$, but how do we prove it in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true in general, for example take $p=2$ and $q=3$, so $p\not\ge q$

$x=5p+q=13$, $y=5p-q=7$, and $2y>x$

Comment: Are there any other counterexamples?

Comment: Quite a number of them: (3,4), (4,5), (4,6), (5,6), (5,7), (6, 7)...

Comment: Sorry for being sloppy. I was talking about pairs (p,q), not (x,y). So for p=4 and q=6 you would have x=26 and y=14

Comment: Generally any positive integers $p$ and $q$ with $p<q<\frac{5p}{3}$ will generate a counterexample

Answer (score 0):

$$5p+q=x$$
$$5p-q=y$$

Solving:

$$p=\frac{x+y}{10}$$
$$q=\frac{x-y}{2}$$

Then:

$$p-q=\frac{3y-2x}{5}\geq0  \iff y\geq\frac{2}{3}x$$

This result implies that the condition is not in general true.

First obviously:
$$2y>x \iff y>\frac{1}{2}x$$
Therefore:
$$y\geq\frac{2}{3}x\gt \frac{1}{2}x$$

So if:

$$\frac{1}{2}x \leq y\lt \frac{2}{3}x$$

The hypothesis will hold but the result would not be true.

Comment: $y\ge\frac{2}{3}x \iff 2y\ge \frac{4}{3}x$, and the hypothesis $2y>x$ does not imply $2y\ge \frac{4}{3}x$, so $p-q\ge 0$ is not necessarily true

Comment: @Momo yes, I said that the condition  to be satisfied is more strong because $y\geq \frac{2}{3}x>\frac{1}{2}x$